# numpy matrix arithmetic with its diagonal element

Tags: python, numpy

I love numpy because it allows vectorized operation such as:

```
mat1 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
mat2 = np.array([[10,20],[30,40]])
mat3 = (mat1 + mat2)*2.0 # vectorization way. nice.
```

But, I can not find how to do this kind of operation with diagonal elements. What I'd like to do is

[image: B_{ij}=1/(A_{i,i}+A_{j,j}-2*A_{i,j})]

[image: B_{ij}=A_{i,j}/\sqrt{A_{i,i}*A_{j,j}}]

Is it possible to operate above in a vectorization way with numpy?

Comment: couldn't you make copies of A, that act like Aii, i.e. all other elements zero?

Answer (score 1):

For the first exemple :

With :

```
In [3]: A
""" 
array([[1, 3, 4, 0, 4],
       [2, 3, 3, 3, 0],
       [1, 0, 4, 1, 0],
       [0, 3, 3, 2, 0],
       [2, 1, 0, 3, 2]])
"""

In [4]: Aii=vstack((diag(A),)*A.shape[0])
"""
array([[1, 3, 4, 2, 2],
       [1, 3, 4, 2, 2],
       [1, 3, 4, 2, 2],
       [1, 3, 4, 2, 2],
       [1, 3, 4, 2, 2]])
"""

In [5]: Ajj=Aii.T # transpose
In [6]: B= 1/ (Aii+Ajj-2*A)
```

Or, with more abstract tools :

```
B1 = 1 / (np.add.outer(diag(A),diag(A))-2*A)
B2 = A / np.sqrt(np.multiply.outer(diag(A),diag(A)))
```

Answer (score 0):

For cases like those with no dependency between iterations, [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) seems like the obvious approach after extending the dimensions of the diagonal 1D array to a 2D version with [`None/np.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) and performing the computations with its 1D version to simulate `A[i,i]` and `A[j,j]` respectively. Thus, to solve those two cases, one could proceed like so -

```
Ad = np.diag(A)  
case1_out_vectorized = 1/(Ad[:,None] + Ad - 2*A)
case2_out_vectorized = A/np.sqrt(Ad[:,None]*Ad)
```

Sample run -

```
In [33]: # Random input array
    ...: A = np.random.rand(4,4)
    ...: 
    ...: # Naive loopy implmentation (used here for verification)
    ...: m = A.shape[0]
    ...: case1_out_loopy = np.zeros((m,m))
    ...: case2_out_loopy = np.zeros((m,m))
    ...: for i in range(m):
    ...:     for j in range(m):
    ...:         case1_out_loopy[i,j] = 1/(A[i,i] + A[j,j] - 2*A[i,j])
    ...:         case2_out_loopy[i,j] = A[i,j]/np.sqrt(A[i,i]*A[j,j])
    ...:         

In [34]: # Proposed approach               
    ...: Ad = np.diag(A)  
    ...: case1_out_vectorized = 1/(Ad[:,None] + Ad - 2*A)
    ...: case2_out_vectorized = A/np.sqrt(Ad[:,None]*Ad)
    ...: 

In [35]: np.allclose(case1_out_loopy,case1_out_vectorized)
Out[35]: True

In [36]: np.allclose(case2_out_loopy,case2_out_vectorized)
Out[36]: True
```